# First Isomorphism Theorem for Rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am trying to get a deeper understanding of the [First Isomorphism Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem), but am having trouble seeing the "natural mapping" that my textbook says exists.  Upon looking it up more online I came across [this](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Understanding_the_isomorphism_theorems) which said that "The map that describes the isomorphism is the real power of the result, rather than the fact that the groups happen to be isomorphic", however, like I said, I am having trouble seeing what mapping this is.  I would appreciate it if you could define the mapping and show that it is a ring homomorphism (both additive and multiplicative).  Thanks!

Note: I do see how the two groups R/K --> Img (R) have the same number of elements, I just can't see the natural bijective homomorphism between the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\phi:R\to S$ be a homomorphism. Then $K=\mathrm{ker}(\phi)$ is an ideal of $R$ and $R/K$ is a ring. The elements of $R/K$ are classes of equivalence: $[x]=[y]\iff x-y\in \mathrm{ker}(\phi).$  Note that then $\phi(x)=\phi(y),$ that is, $\phi$ takes a unique value on each class of equivalence. Moreover, $[x]\ne [y]\iff x-y\notin \mathrm{ker}(\phi)\iff \phi(x)\ne \phi(y).$  That is, $\phi$ takes different values on different classes of equivalence.

Thus the map that defines in a natural way the isomorphism is

$$R/\mathrm{ker}(\phi)\to \mathrm{im}(\phi), [x]\to \phi(x).$$

It follows from above that it is well-defined. Can you prove that it is an isomorphim?

Comment: when you say classes of equivalence, are you speaking of the fibers over the elements in the image? (i.e [x] = {$a \in R$ | $ a = \phi ^{-1} (x)$})  Sorry, I've just yet to learn about classes of equivalences.

Comment: Yes. But note that you write $[x]$ with $x\in S.$ You should use the notation $[b]=\{a\in R| a = \phi ^{-1} (\phi(b))\}.$